# Ajax call in symfony to filter table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, symfony, doctrine

I am new at Symfony.

I have 2 entities Position and Candidat with relationship as in a position we can have multiple candidats.

Now I have a dropdown populate by positions and below a table with a list of candidat.

I want filter list of candidat when I select a position using the dropdown.

below the codes:

*Controller*

```
/**
* @Route(name="filter",path="/filter")
* @param Request $request
*/
public function test2Action(Request $request)
{   
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$positions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Position')->findAll();
$candidats = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Candidat')->findAll();

if($request->request->get('myselect')){

$val = $request->request->get('myselect');
$candidats = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Candidat')->find($val);
return $this->render('postionsearch.html.twig',  
array( 'candidats'  => $candidats , 'positions' => $positions ) );
}

return $this->render('postionsearch.html.twig',  
array( 'candidats'  => $candidats , 'positions' => $positions ) );
}
```

*twig*:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<select  name="position" id="selectpos">
<option ></option>
{% for position in positions %}
<option value="{{ position.id }}">{{ position.titre }} 
</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>   
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
<div id="ajax-results">Results : </div>

{% if candidats  is defined %}
<table id="dataTable">
<tbody>
{% for candidat in candidats %}
<tr>
<td>{{candidat.id}}</td>
<td>{{candidat.nom}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

{% endif  %}
```

*JS*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 
asset('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("jQuery is ready");
$("#selectpos").change(function(){
var value= $( "#selectpos option:selected" ).val();
$.ajax({
url:'{{ (path('filter')) }}',
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {
"myselect": value
},
async: true,
success: function (data)
{
console.log(data)
$('#ajax-results').html(data.output);
},
error: function (err)
{
console.log(err.statusText);
}
});

return false;
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: [See how you can format and indent your code correctly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); please indent your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass filter parameter to your action:

```
/**
* @Route(name="filter",path="/filter/{positionId}")
* @param Request $request
*/
```

Or do it via get:

```
$request->get('positionId')
```

And then use it as a criteria in your repository:

```
$positions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Position')->findBy([
    'positionId' => $positionId
]);
```

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'path_to_your_controller',
    data: {
        "myselect": value
    })
```